# QuickTime can't play 4k video while VLC can

Tags: macos, audio, video, quicktime, vlc

I'm on mountain lion 10.8.5 and recently my friend gave me a 4K resolution video. When I used QuickTime player, the video is very sharp and some of the text in it can't be seen correctly. However when I used VLC to play it, it played without any errors and I can clearly see the text. I like the UI of QuickTime player, so is there any way to make it appear on QT?

Comment: Is your video file an mp4 or an avi/mkv  ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler It's a `.mp4` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be honest : appart of the UI, Quicktime X a crapy software in term of compatibility. And it became crappier since the development of [Perian](http://www.perian.org/) has stopped. And on Mavericks it's even worse (Perian doesn't work anymore ...). The cause : QuickTime X is based on the [AV Foundation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) which is only powerful with H.264 stuff (yeah the file format sold on iTunes).

VLC is powered by a different video library than QuickTime and it's know to be one of the most compatible player yet.

**TLDR:** So no there is no there is no solution yet. Let's hope the situation will evolve.

Comment: Think I'm going to stick with VLC.

Comment: Perian was the bomb!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [MPlayerX](http://mplayerx.org). It has a very clean interface and works very well, supporting pretty much any format like VLC (and unlike QuickTime, which supports pretty much nothing).

Comment: Think I'm going to stick with VLC.